# Can I buy a one-way ticket to Australia with an indefinite visa?

Tags: bookings, australia, iranian-citizens

I have an Iranian passport and an Australian class 101, multiple-entry visa with indefinite stay.
Could I buy a one-way ticket to Australia?

Comment: Yes. Why not? An indefinite stay means you don’t have to prove means of going back soon

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can buy a one way ticket to Australia. This visa entitles you to [remain permanently in Australia](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/101-).